# How do you set a default value for a variable in Python3?

Tags: python, default-value, default-constructor

For an assignment I have to write a program that can create directories and files, we have to write a DirectoryEntry class to help do this, and for part of it we have to create a name for the file or directory. If a name is entered then we just use the name but if no name is entered we just use 9 spaces.

I don't know how to do this using the `__init__` method because Python3 doesn't allow you to have more then one constructor method.

Right now it just looks like:

```
def __init__(self, name):
    self.type = "f:"
    self.name = name
    self.length = "0000"
    self.colon = ":"
    self.blocks = ["000", "000", "000", "000", "000", "000", "000", "000", "000", "000", "000", "000"]`
```

Comment: You can have a default parameter, provided it is not a mutable object.  For example: `def __init__(self, name='         '):`.  However, is 9 spaces a sensible filename?

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
def __init__(self, name='your_default_name'):
```

Then you can either create an object of that class with `my_object()` and it will use the default value, or use `my_object('its_name')` and it will use the input value.

Answer (score 1):

Just set it like this, so for default will use 9 spaces

```
def __init__(self, name='        '):
        self.type = "f:"
        self.name = name
        self.length = "0000"
        self.colon = ":"
        self.blocks = ["000", "000", "000", "000", "000", "000", "000", "000", "000", "000", "000", "000"]
```

[More information](http://blog.thedigitalcatonline.com/blog/2015/02/11/default-arguments-in-python/#.V9EpHE2LQdU)

Answer (score 1):

Specify it as a default variable as shown below

```
def __init__(self, name=' '*9):
    self.type = "f:"
    self.name = name
    self.length = "0000"
    self.colon = ":"
    self.blocks = ["000", "000", "000", "000", "000", "000", "000","000","000","000", "000", "000"]
```

Comment: They could shorten `self.blocks = ["000"] * 12` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use default arguments:

```
def __init__(self, name='         '):
```